# how to filter WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a WP_Query

`$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'showposts' => -1 ) );`, and it retrieves all the posts that have post type = "testimonials",

So

I need to filter them according to the posts that have metakey = "rate" and metavalue <= 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
     'post_type' => 'testimonials', 
     'showposts' => -1,
     'meta_key' => 'rate',
     'meta_value' => 4,
     'meta_compare' => '<='
   ) 
);
```